# How does Obi app estimates bolt taxi prices

Tags: api, estimation, bolt, ride

From the official documentation of bolt taxi app, they have listed there is no private or public Api. How does Obi taxi app shows the estimate of bolt?

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bellhop.app

Answer (score 0):

They most likely reverse engineered the API used by the app.